How can I return additional properties with an object on an API response?
I am returning an object in my API call. I would like to add some additional data to return along with this object but as a part of the object.
The simplified code is given below.
<HttpGet>
Public Function GetEntity(Code As String) As IHttpActionResult

    Dim Ent As New EntityClass
    Ent.Load(Code)

    Ent.NewProp1 = NewObject1  ' NewProp1 Doesn't exist
    Ent.NewProp2 = NewObject2  ' NewProp2 Doesn't exist

    Return Ok(Ent)
End Function

Is this a way to do this other than declaring another class with all properties?

VB supports anonymous types, are you just looking for that?

@David No, I need to add the properties to an existing class and return as a single object.

In that case you'd probably need to add the properties to that class.  Another alternative could be to create a wrapper object which has the original object as a property and any additional properties you like alongside it.

Related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/handle-overflow or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.extensiondataobject?view=net-8.0

@Mitch Thanks, this is very helpful. Not directly in this case, but we can use JsonExtensionData in many other cases.
